# Sort! seems to ignore custom attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method to place 'The' at the end of a string if it is at the beginning of the string in `Novel.class`:

```
def sort_name
    display_name = self.name
    if display_name.match(/^the/i)
      arr = display_name.split(/^the/i)
      display_name = "#{arr[1]}, The"
    end
    display_name
```

I have this index method in `NovelController`:

```
def index
  @novels = Novel.all

  @novels.to_a.sort! { |a,b| a.sort_name.downcase <=> b.sort_name.downcase }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @novels }
  end
end
```

In the view I just display the `sort_name`.  The `sort_name` is being displayed but the novels are still ordered by `name`.  Does anybody see a flaw?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that sorted array is discarded.

```
@novels.to_a
```

This returns a temporary array (which isn't saved anywhere). That temp array is then sorted in-place and forgotten, because you don't have any references to it.

Solution: save it into a variable.

```
@novels = Novel.all.sort { |a,b| a.sort_name.downcase <=> b.sort_name.downcase }
```

Also, you have a bug in your `sort_name` code. It returns values like these:

```
# for name "The Yellow God"
display_name # => " Yellow God, The"
```

Comment: For some reason, that actually places all of the modified strings before the defaults.  For example, "Yellow God, The" is before "Allan and..." Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @JoeEssey: hmm, maybe activerecord batching is misbehaving. Try getting full array: `Novel.all.to_a.sort ...`

Comment: That's actually what I've got:  `@novels = Novel.all.to_a.sort { |a,b| a.sort_name.downcase <=> b.sort_name.downcase }`

Comment: @JoeEssey: your `display_name` is bugged. Returns `display_name # => " Yellow God, The"`

Comment: Please add a new answer if you wish.  `sort!` allows you to keep the sorted array in the same var.  As you've illustrated that's not the problem.

Comment: @JoeEssey: If you leave the controller code as in the question, your sorted results will still be discarded. You know that, right?

Comment: Amended this answer instead.